# Runtime Libraries error - C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have just published my C# Windows Form Application and when I try and run the setup file on my client's computer I am greeted with this message:

> *Setup has detected that the file 'Link\vc_redist.x64.exe' has changed since it was initially published.*

I am not sure what this means. I have a feeling it is something to do with the **Prerequisites** I am trying to install. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What is the architecture of your program set to: any, win32, x86 or x64.  Does it use any 32 bit DLLs?

Comment: I've developed it as an x64 and I am trying to install the x64 Runtime Libraries on my client's computer.

Comment: vc_redist is normally for C++ programs.  For C# you'll need the correct version of .net framework.  How was the setup created - Wix, MS installer?

Comment: I used MS Installer :)

Comment: If you right click on the setup project, select properties then select Prerequisites, which options are ticked?

Comment: The only one I've got ticked is 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)'

Comment: Is there a follow up message that says something like _"See the setup log file located at ‘C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\…\install.log’ for more information."_?

Comment: **`1)`** Unless you do platform invokes from C# I don't think you need the VCRuntime? **`2)`** Have you tried to run the setup.exe again on a clean virtual or after a reboot of the box with the problem message? **`3)`** Have you set the **`setup.exe`** to download the runtime from vendor site, or do you include a version you downloaded and compile that into the setup? **`4)`** What kind of distribution scope is this? Company-wide, third party deployment world-wide or what and what OS do you want to support? You might find that it is easier to just deliver an MSI and no setup.exe.

Comment: I should add that you can use a **`launch condition`** - or a **`read-only custom action`** - to detect if your prerequisites are installed from within the MSI. Most any computer that is set up for real-world use will have **`VCRuntime`** and a version of the **`.NET framework`** installed. Certainly so in a corporate environment (where **`setup.exe`** wrappers and outdated runtimes included is a favorite annoyance).

Comment: Really appreciate your help, thanks :)